# List of length $x$, with letters $A$ and $B$, how many ways? (Basic Combinatorics Question)

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

I was tasked with finding the number of possible ways of writing a sequence with the following conditions:

1. Sequence has a length $x$, where $x$ is even
2. Sequence consists of the letters $A$ and $B$
3. The number of $A$s must equal the numbers of $B$s

For example, for $x=4$, these are all the valid sequences:

```
AABB, ABAB, BABA, ABBA, BAAB, BBAA
```

I was able to quickly find out that the answer was $\binom{x}{x/2}$ just by pattern (in this case $\binom{4}{2}=6$), but am having trouble understanding why that is the solution i.e expression for phrasing the solution.

There are $x$ slots to fill, which are to be filled with two letters, but $\binom{x}{2}$ would just give me the number of lists of length two. Here I'm trying to find the number of lists of length $x$ with the same number of $A$s and $B$s.

I guess to rephrase my question, how could you translate the phrase "$x$ choose $x/2$" in the context of this problem?

Follow-up question I was thinking about: if $x$ is an odd number, how would we have to modify our expression? For example, if we must use three $A$s and two $B$s, and our $x=5$.

Answer (score 2):

Let me rephrase the original question slightly: for each $n\in\Bbb N$ you want to count the sequences of $n$ $A$’s and $n$ $B$’s. (In other words, your $x$ is my $2n$.) There are $2n$ positions in such a sequence, and any $n$ of them can be filled with the $n$ $A$’s. Once you know which $n$ positions hold the $A$’s, you know that the remaining $n$ positions must hold the $B$’s, so you actually know the whole sequence. Thus, you can count the sequences by counting the ways to place $n$ $A$’s in a string of $2n$ positions. That’s just the number of ways of choosing $n$ of the $2n$ positions, which is given by the binomial coefficient $\binom{2n}n$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, very succinct and more clear. The expression nA's in a string of 2n positions helped a lot (for the odd question, I can replace 2n with 2n+1). I also just realized that 5 choose 3 = 5 choose 2 etc, very cool result and I understand it now.

Comment: @NoobCoder: Excellent! You’re welcome.